# How to print a specific character from a string in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, nested-loops, c-strings

I'm recently practicing looping. I learned how to print: for example `home` to `h` `ho` `hom` `home`. by using

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){
    char s[100];
    
    printf("Input string = ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", s);
    
    for (int i=1; i<=strlen(s); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<i; j++)
        printf("%c", s[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
```

How can i reverse it so it can be
`home`
`hom`
`ho`
`h`
instead? thank you.

Comment: Don't use scanf: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html. In this case, you should just do `char *s = argv[1]`.  If you're going to use `scanf`, there are many issues to watch out for, but at the very least protect yourself by doing:  `if( scanf("%99[^\n]", s) != 1 ){ exit(1);}`

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]", s);` is worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359). Do not use either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to do. For example

```
for ( size_t i = strlen( s ); i != 0; i-- )
{
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < i; j++ )
    { 
        putchar( s[j] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Another way is the following

```
for ( size_t i = strlen( s ); i != 0; i-- )
{
    printf( ".*s\n", ( int )i, s );
}
```

provided that an object of the type `int` is able to store the length of the passed string.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "home";

    for (size_t i = strlen( s ); i != 0; i--)
    {
        printf( "%.*s\n", ( int )i, s );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
home
hom
ho
h
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation, it helped me in my way of learning, i didn't think of that way because i'm a newbie. if you mind if i ask. what should i do if i want it to be `home` `ome` `me` `e`? Thank you.

Comment: @atuy It is easy. for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen( s ); i < n; i++ ) puts( s + i );

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over the string using `putc`, but it might also be helpful to understand the destructive approach that shortens the string and uses `%s` to print strings.  eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *s = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : strdup("home");
    for( char *e = s + strlen(s); e > s; e -= 1 ){
        *e = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this approach is destructive.  When complete, the string is null.  As an exercise, it might be helpful to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll basically go backwards in your loop.

Instead of:

```
    for (int i=1; i<=strlen(s); i++){
```

You'd have

```
    for (int i=strlen(s); i>0; i--){
```

Comment: @atuy try to learn :) which loop controls this behavior? Basically you need to figure out where to start your index count in that loop and which way to move through it. You have ```i``` and ```j``` and ```++``` and ```--``` - figure out which one of each it should be